# how to print per column use awk

Tags: awk

the content of a.txt

```
name age
alice 21
ryan 30
```

```
#test.sh
nf=`awk '{print NF; exit}' a.txt`
for((i=1;i<=$nf;i++))
{
    awk '{print $i}' ./a.txt
}
```

The result I expected is print per column,but the actual result is print all content twice.

my expected output is

```
name
alice
ryan
age
21
30
```

actual output is

```
name age
alice 21
ryan 30
name age
alice 21
ryan 30
```

Comment: please include a expected output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `$i` is only visible to `bash`, not `awk`. You need to pass it into your awk script as:

```
awk -v i=$i '{print $i}' ./a.txt
```

The `-v` option allows you to pass variables into `awk`. `i=$i` means the `$i` in your awk script will be `$i` in your bash.

If other tools are allowed, you can try

```
cut -f $i a.txt
```

as a simpler candicate.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done in a single `awk` itself, please try following; written and tested with your show samples.

```
awk -v tot="0" '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    arr[i]=(arr[i]?arr[i] ORS:"")$i
  }
  tot=(tot>NF?tot:NF)
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=tot;i++){
    print arr[i]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v tot="0" '          ##Starting awk program from here, setting tot to 0 here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){     ##Traversing through all fields here.
    arr[i]=(arr[i]?arr[i] ORS:"")$i  ##Creating arr with index of i and keep appending current field value in it.
  }
  tot=(tot>NF?tot:NF)     ##Creating tot by seeing current total number of fields, to get highest NF value here.
}
END{                      ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i=1;i<=tot;i++){    ##Running for loop from i=1 to till tot value here.
    print arr[i]          ##Printing array with index of i here.
  }
}
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Very well explained answer ++

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `gawk` without saving inside `array`, if you prefer saving resource/memory:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 && ++fcount<NF{
        delete ARGV[fcount]
        ARGV[fcount+1]=FILENAME
        ARGC++
     }
     {
        print $(fcount)
     }
    ' file
```

**Results:**

```
$ cat file 
name age
alice 21
ryan 30


$ awk 'FNR==1 && ++fcount<NF{delete ARGV[fcount];ARGV[fcount+1]=FILENAME;ARGC++}{print $(fcount)}END{for(i in ARGV)print i,ARGV[i]}' file
name
alice
ryan
age
21
30
```

Comment: Atleast  over 1 million columns it works, max possible args limits probably  [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) can tell

Comment: probably `INT_MAX` ?

Comment: An interesting approach ++

Comment: I expect the max varies by awk version and the box you're running it on but I really don't know and you could avoid that issue by only adding the next file name to ARGV[] while processing the current file up to the original ARGC instead of adding them all at once in the BEGIN. The speed impact of opening the input file a million times would, I think, be a bigger concern.

Comment: Having said that, the OP is currently looping once per field anyway and I doubt there will really be a million fields so I expect in reality this solution would work just fine.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes in current scenario it is fine, changes done now

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a shell loop, just 1 call to awk. Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        vals[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) {
            print vals[j,i]
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk a.txt
name
alice
ryan
age
21
30
```

or, if you prefer, with GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    vals[NR][1]
    split($0,vals[NR])
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) {
            print vals[j][i]
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk a.txt
name
alice
ryan
age
21
30
```

Answer (score 0):

And with`awk` without using any array, you can get the expected output:

```
awk  'NR==FNR{print $1;next}{print $2}' file file
name
alice
ryan
age
21
30
```